# Excel 2010 split cells with commas without spaces (vs. commas with spaces)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I've been doing a lot of research to figure this out, but all the answers require either to split all data by all commas (i.e., every time a comma appears, it gets split) or knowing the exact location of the comma (i.e., it's the third comma).

What I need is more variable than that. I get data exported in a list in one cell, where data that needs to stay in the same cell is separated by commas with spaces (e.g., "dog, cat" not "dog,cat"). I need the splits to occur at the latter ("dog,cat"), but not in the former ("dog, cat"). This occurs varying amounts of times based on the data itself.

For example, one cell might say this:

Dog Walk, Talk, and Wag,Cat Meow, Hiss, and Purr,Parrot Squawk and Talk,Duck Quack and Talk

Where I would need it to look like this:

cell 1: Dog Walk, Talk, and Wag

cell 2: Cat Meow, Hiss, and Purr

cell 3: Parrot Squawk and Talk

cell 4: Duck Quack and Talk

But another cell will have different words and different comma placement.

Is there any way to do this?

Thank you!!

Comment: VBA is the only way to do a split based on a comma followed by something other than a space. Are you open to a solution in VBA? FYI if you respond, please put @Eric F in front of it for me to see your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I have had to do something like this, I used the **Find and Replace** function to temporarily "hide" the character combination before separating the columns.

The process goes basically like this:

1. Select all the text to be split into columns.
2. Use **Find and Replace** to change all the comma-space combinations to something else that is not found in the data (I usually use something like `@@@`).
3. Run the **Text to Columns** function, splitting on the commas.
4. Select all the newly created columns.
5. Run the **Find and Replace** again, but reverse it so the `@@@` are changed back into the comma-space pair.

Comment: +1 on this, I also use this method but instead of find and replace  I prefer to use a formula like: =SUBSTITUTE(A1,", ","@@@") in column B and then copy/paste special as values, and use with the **Text to Columns**  function. maybe a little step extra but guarantees original text remains untouched. Gives me peace of mind.

Answer (score 0):

This is  VBA macro implementing techturtle's solution.  Select the cells you wish to process and run this short macro:

```
Sub splitText()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, a As Variant, i As Long
    Set rng = Selection.Cells.SpecialCells(2)

    For Each r In rng
        v = r.Value
        If InStr(1, v, ",") > 0 Then
            ary = Split(Replace(v, ", ", Chr(1)), ",")
            i = 1
            For Each a In ary
                r.Offset(0, i).Value = Replace(a, Chr(1), ", ")
                i = i + 1
            Next a
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

[image]

The original data is untouched.

**NOTE:**

This code is specific to cells containing constants rather than formulas.